# Fazer um withCount dentro de outro relacionamento que ta dentro de um relacionamento

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho 3 tabelas, Cliente, Orcamento e OrdemServicos.

```
$clientes = Cliente::withCount('orcamento')->orderBy('orcamento_count', 'desc')->get();
```

o código acima me retorna oque eu preciso, mas eu preciso do seguinte

preciso fazer um withCount na tabela "ordemservico" porém elá está dentro da tabela  de "orcamento" que está relacionada.

precisava de algo do tipo como por exemplo...

```
$clientes = Cliente::withCount(['orcamento','ordemservico'])->orderBy('ordemservico_count', 'desc')->get();
```

alguma ideia ?

Comment: Acho que seria mais ou menos assim:
`$clientes = Cliente::withCount(['orcamento' => function (Builder $query) {
    $query->withCount(['ordemservico']);
}])->orderBy('orcamento_count', 'desc')->get();
`

Comment: testei deu esse erro mano.. "Argument 1 passed to App\Repositories\ClientesRepository::App\Repositories\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Repositories\Builder, instance of Illuminate\D"

Comment: eu tentei fazendo assim... "$clientes = Cliente::withCount('orcamento','orcamento.ordemservico')->orderBy('orcamento_count', 'desc')->get();" acho que assim seria a forma correta não é ?